# Cómo hallar la diferencia tiempo datetime.now()

Tags: python, django

Estoy trabajando en un software de parqueadero usando django. En él se registra hora de ingreso y hora de salida (con sus respectivas fechas). Ahora necesito sacar la diferencia para determinar el valor a cobrar.

```
HoraIngreso = obj.horaIngreso # (se extrae de lo alacenado en el modelo)
```

Este es el valor de lo que me devuelve:

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 1, 22, 0, 21, 979170, tzinfo=<UTC>)
HoraSalida = datetime.now()
```

Este es el valor de lo que me devuelve:

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 4, 17, 22, 26, 25698)
diferencia = HoraSalida - HoraIngreso
```

Este es el error que devuelve:

```
TypeError: "can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes"
```

Answer (score 1):

Como el datetime de `HoraIngreso` lo tienes en *UTC* puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
HoraSalida = datetime.utcnow() # Fíjate en que se usa la función 'utcnow', no 'now'
diferencia = HoraSalida - HoraIngreso
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es un problema con la TimeZone.

Este error:

> TypeError: "can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes"

Esta solución sirve tanto para `django` como por `php`, que se soluciona simplemente quitando el TimeZone de la hora:

```
diferencia = HoraSalida.replace(tzinfo=None) - HoraIngreso.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

No trabajo con este lenguaje, pero prueba a descomponer la fecha en:
dia = now.day();
mes = now.month();
año = now.year();

Resta lo que te interese y vuelve a concatenar los tres valores.